# Bypass PHP's str_replace() when replacing a single character

Tags: php, security, shell, str-replace

So, I am studying some PHP security using DVWA (http://www.dvwa.co.uk/). Right now I'm on an exercise where the author tries to teach us to execute commands on vulnerable applications. In this level, [it adds a very simple blacklist which removes important characters](https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/blob/master/vulnerabilities/exec/source/medium.php):

```
$substitutions = array(
        '&&' => '',
        ';' => '',
    );
```

I obviously can use some other characters to still get code executed (like `|`, `||`, `&`, etc.), but I wanted to know how I'd evade the substitution for the single character "`;`". I've seen some examples around which fools the substitution with code like "`<scr<script>ipt>`" and I've tried stuff like "`;;;`"; tried to encode in hex and base64 and such but it didn't work.

Is there a way to evade `str_replace()` when it is looking for a single character? This is PHP 5.5.3.

Comment: You can with regex replace?

Comment: What are you doing with the incoming string?  Why are you using `str_replace`?  Most functions have their own "escape" function that you should be using.  (eg. `mysql_real_escape_string` and `escapeshellcmd`)

Comment: What do you mean by "evade the substitution"?  What does that mean?  What examples have you seen?

Comment: `$str = bin2hex(';');
// ...
echo hex2bin($str);`

Comment: I'm not the author. That is an application to show the common security mistakes developers make and teach how to exploit and correct them. The author used it to show a possible solution some devs use (blacklisting known bad stuff), and wants me to understand how to bypass that - showing me that it is not a good solution.

Comment: That piece of core is later used by str_replace to replace the "bad characters" I sent through the form in order to stop the attack. I was able to evade that protection and get my code executed. But I want to know how to bypass the ';' which is on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [page](https://nets.ec/Command_Injection) to be useful when I was doing this. It turns out there are other operators which can be used other than ';' to plug your own command in!

The "hard" setting on this is currently causing myself some trouble, I think there may be a workaround using URL encoded characters or something of the sort, but it remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the author is showing how to use a black-list, its too easily subverted, perhaps this idea is shredded further on in the tut.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling

Although the example you link to is the 'medium' level, even the 'harder' level does not use PHPs Filter FILTER_VALIDATE_IP

Even a REGEX would do a better job. See half way down the page of:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

If you are trying to protect against XSS attacks (you mention a mangled script tag) then white-listing is the way to go. Validate against what you expect to get, or abort.

**EDIT**

Hmmm.. now I see the site is called Damned Vulnerable Web App, perhaps the idea is to teach you all the poor examples ...

Comment: Indeed, it shows me the bad coding practices. I was able to evade the protection using other characters, that are not in the list and I understood how to evade and trick str_replace using strings like "<scr<script>ipt>" to form a single "<script>" tag and still inject the attack. But I wasn't able to find an example that bypasses a single character, like ";". Is that possible?